# Solid in Liquid Heat Transfer (Temperatures/Entropy Changes)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

Suppose we have a solid of temperature $T_s$ and heat capacity $C_p$ submerged into a pool of water that has temperature $T_w$.

If $T_s \gt T_w$ and the pressure of the isolated pool-solid system is constant, how much heat will the solid lose, how much heat will the pool gain and what will the entropy change be for every part?

*Edit* I do understand that the format of the question resembles that of a plain exercise. However, aid in a question as such will mostly help me understand what kind of a process this heat transmission is and how it could be described mathematically. That said, I have indeed worked on the question and reached a certain point of progress but would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please show us what you got so far.  Also, please understand that the final state and the changes in temperature and entropy of the solid and the water for this irreversible process are independent of the details of the process.

Comment: Here is a link to a cookbook recipe for determining the change in entropy for an irreversible process such as this:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: For a start, thank you for your answer. 
Well, concerning my progress, from the formula δq=Cp*dT (for the solid), I got via integration that Δq=Cp*(Ts'-Ts)<0, where Ts' is the occuring temperature of the solid after its immersion in the lake.
Moreover, I know that for the solid dS=δq/Τ which, via integration, gives the formula ΔS=Cp=lnT

Comment: I assume that you are looking for the steady state answer?  If not, are you looking for a function of heat transfer vs. time?

Comment: Before you can get the entropy changes, you need to apply the first law to get the final temperature of the water and the solid.  What result do you get for this final temperature?

Comment: Well, I checked the recipe you gave me and have to admit it was quite useful. I now know that the process is for certain irreversible and that the first law of thermodynamics has to be applied. 
Now, there is obviously no work done from the solid to the body of water and vice versa, so the work part is erased. Well, that leads to dU=Q=TdS.
What I don't get however, is how to get from there to the final temperatures.
I mean, what more do we know of the internal energy?

Comment: The change in internal energy of the water is $$\Delta U_w=M_wC_{vw}(T_f-T_{wi})$$and the change in internal energy of the solid is $$\Delta U_s=M_sC_{vs}(T_f-T_{si})$$ where $T_f$ is the final temperature.  Since the total change in internal energy for this system is zero (no heat is transferred to the combination of water and solid), these two changes in internal energy must add up to zero.

Comment: Do you understand so far, and, if so, do you want me to continue with the analysis?

Comment: Well, @ChetMiller, I did grasp the idea, so thank you for your analysis. It is evident that by use of these formulas and the energy balance equations, I shall be able to determine the final temperatures thus solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the general case: When matter is heated or cooled under constant pressure, the amount of heat is 
$$
   Q = \Delta H
$$
and the entropy change is
$$
   \Delta S = \int \frac{dH}{T}
$$
In the special case that there is no phase change and the heat capacity is constant, then
$$
    Q = m\, C_P (T_f - T_i)
$$
and
$$
      \Delta S = m\, C_P \ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}
$$
where $T_i$ and $T_f$ is the initial and final temperature. The last two equations will solve your problem. First write the energy balance to find out what is the final temperature. Once you know the final temperature, calculate the heat and entropy.